# PHP Multipage survey - moving to the next part

Tags: php, session, isset

I'm creating a survey based on a list of multiple choice questions, where the user clicks the button on each page to transition to the next question.

The set up I have now, each question is an individual form, with each each choice being a submit button containing the value of their answer.  My problem is that with this set up the user has to click the answer twice (or refresh the page) to move on to the next part of the survey.  I understand why this is currently happening as I know it has to be reloaded to run the php again to check if the `$_SESSION` is set.

I'm just now sure how I should modify it to get around this problem.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['part1'])) { 
         $survey_question = "surveyQuestions and answers here";
         if (isset($_POST['part1'])) {
             $_SESSION['part1'] = $_POST['part1'];
         }
} else if (!isset($_SESSION['part2'])) { 
         $survery_question = "next questions and answers form"; 
... }

echo $survey_question;
```

I added an onClick event to each submit button to have the page reloaded via javascript to no avail.

Comment: Could you show the HTML and some more code. I don't understand why you have to click twice. When you submit page 1, it should just save the values of the page 1 answers in the session, and display page 2.

Comment: If you're not using a database, you might as well do everything in JavaScript. If you are using a database, or must have Server information, use AJAX.

Comment: Everything is running off of the same page, so when it first launches it's echoing part 1, then it's refreshing the same page to echo part 2.  Should I be making separate files for each question?

Comment: @PHPglue I'll be adding the value's to the database once the survey is completed

Comment: You should use AJAX. You use JavaScript to send information to the Sever and await a response. This way you don't even need multiple pages for your survey.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to using PHP here?  Apart from the current problem I'm having PHP seems to be doing the trick

Comment: You will want to use PHP to store information in your database, upon each JavaScript AJAX call. You may even want to store information in a `$_SESSION` so it can be shared across your domain, as each AJAX call loads a new PHP page. The disadvantage of using the submit button is that it reloads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you could add a hidden value in the question form that indicates what question they just answered.

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="questionNum" value="1" />
...
```

Then inside your php file, grab this value and use it to display the next question.

```
$question_num = (isset($_POST['questionNum'])) ? (int)$_POST['questionNum'] : 0;

switch($question_num) {
    case 0:
        $survey_question = "Question 1.";
        break;
    case 1:
        if(isset($_POST['part1'])) {
            $_SESSION['part1'] = $_POST['part1'];
        }

        $survey_question = "Question 2.";
        break;
     case 2:
        ...
}
```

When the user firsts go to the php page, the question number will be set to `0` and this will display the first question. When they submit the page again, the `questionNum` POST variable will be set to `1` and this will save the first answer in the session and then print out the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of ajax is a great idea, however this can be done without javascript. You can simply submit to the same page(.php) collecting right values using an hidden input and checking for this with a if statement in your script